# Using json online

Tags: javascript, html, json, discord.js

Heyo!

So, I'm trying to make something like https://aws.random.cat/meow however, when using my code with a discord bot, it isn't working.. It makes me wonder if you can host json things online directly by using the below code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre style=\"word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;\">{\"file\":\"https:\\/\\/"+domain+"\\/images\\/hug\\/"+item+"\"}</pre>";
```

Furthermore, my bot code is:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const axios = require('axios');
const {get} = require("snekfetch");

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTitle("thingie")
        .setDescription("Loading...")
message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {
    get('https://example.com/kiss').then(response => {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            embed.setDescription("")
            embed.setImage(response.body.file)
            msg.edit(embed)
        }, 1500);
    });
})
```

My website is working perfectly and is showing exactly as in https://aws.random.cat/meow However, it still doesn't work. Please lmk how or why this is happening.

P.S I didn't include the modules.export part in the bot code cuz, I thought it was extra.

P.P.S The following is my current output: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqgXF.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: what json are you referring to?

Comment: the {"file": "whatever"} part (refer to image)

Comment: Please don't assume people can read code from an image. Consider editing the question and include it as text?

Comment: The code is included as text there.. The image is the output (I've written there that my current output is the image, read the P.P.S) If you haven't read the question properly, please don't make any assumptions

Comment: That's not JSON. That's an HTML element that contains text which contains JSON. Try removing the `pre` element? If you try to parse the document body using `JSON.parse` it's going to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to provide data in a JSON format on your endpoint then just provide the JSON part, no need to put it in an HTML. If you put your JSON inside HTML like a string, then when you do `get(<your url>)` you'll get the entire HTML code with the embedded JSON, and so `response.file` doesn't work.

The reason why https://aws.random.cat/meow shows up as being embedded within HTML is because the browser detects that it is a JSON file and hence it does the embedding automatically. Here is the RAW response from that URL when you try to make the request using `wget` on the command line:

```sh
$ wget https://aws.random.cat/meow --no-check-certificate
$ cat meow
{"file":"https:\/\/purr.objects-us-east-1.dream.io\/i\/935392_10151612620866211_62628372_n.jpg"}
```

As you can see, there's no HTML around it. It's pure JSON.

To verify that this is indeed the case, log the response you get from your url:

```js
get('https://example.com/kiss').then(response => {
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

Unrelated: anyone else appreciate the `cat meow` coincidence here?

Comment: Wait, so, I removed the pre parts in the document.body.innerHTML part however, when I log the response.body, I get this: `<Buffer 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0d 0a 3c 68 74 6d 6c 20 6c 61 6e 67 3d 22 65 6e 22 3e 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 0d 0a 20 20 20 ... 5759 more bytes>` soo... any idea?

Comment: try `console.log(response.body.toString())`. Looks like its a buffer that needs to be converted - https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_buffer_tostring.asp. Alternatively, have you tried doing `wget` for your url? I put your hex output in a hex->string converter and I can see that it is still HTML code.

Comment: I just realised that it has to be response.body.file because it is in the json value "file" obviously however, I just get a response of undefined :( (I haven't tried wget because I'm using windows and powershell does not want to work with me.. I might as well send the link: https://idk1234.000webhostapp.com/hug)

Comment: This is what your url returns: https://ibb.co/s6Jy1Fr. Like I said, this is HTML and so you can't access it like a JSON. Instead of using an HTML file, just upload your JSON data as a .json file and use that file's URL